# Server-side 3D rendering tool to use with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, 3d, rendering

I was wondering, are there any known 3D modeling/rendering tools which would play well with Rails?

Say, I want to make a scene of a room in my browser (client-side, using html5, for example), send it over to a rendering server (send data that describes the room, using JSON), and then have a realistic JPEG picture back from the server.

Do you know any software I can use to build such system?

I heard about [Open CASCADE Community Edition](https://github.com/tpaviot/oce/), but not sure if it suits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with [Ogre](https://github.com/abexsoft/ruby-ogre) and, maybe, some [OpenGL wrapper](https://github.com/davll/ruby-opengl) for Ruby.